# Pass parameter from input to onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm looking to pass the input phone number, into the callCustomer() function on my button.

How would I got about this.

```
<button onclick="callCustomer(document.getElementById('#phone'))" type="button" name="call" id="call" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg call-customer-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  Call customer
</button>

<input type="text" id="phone" name"phone">
```

The following return null

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery or not? Since you don't code with jQuery but your question is tagged with jQuery.

Comment: remove # from #phone

Comment: or use `document.querySelector()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is because you have the `#` prefix on the `id` value you provide to `getElementById()`. That should be removed.

However it should be noted that it's much better practice to use unobtrusive event handlers instead of inline ones. Secondly, as the `input` you're trying to get the value of has an `id` it would be easier to read its value from the DOM when the event occurs. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's an example using that:

```js
$('#call').on('click', function() {
  var phone = $('#phone').val();
  
  console.log(phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="call" id="call" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg call-customer-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Call customer
</button>

<input type="text" id="phone" name "phone" value="07777 777 777" />
```

Should you need it, here's the plain JS equivalent:

```js
document.getElementById('call').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  console.log(phone);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" name="call" id="call" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg call-customer-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Call customer
</button>

<input type="text" id="phone" name "phone" value="07777 777 777" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#` from the selector as `getElementById()` treats the parameter value as `id` by default. Then use the `value` property of the passed element inside the function:

```js
function callCustomer(el){
  console.log(el.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="callCustomer(document.getElementById('phone'))" type="button" name="call" id="call" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg call-customer-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  Call customer
</button>

<input type="text" id="phone" name"phone">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function callCustomer(id)
{
//Javascript
 console.log(id.value);
//or
 console.log(document.getElementById('phone').value);
 //or  --Jquery
  console.log($('#phone').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="callCustomer(document.getElementById('phone'))" type="button" name="call" id="call" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg call-customer-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  Call customer
</button>

<input type="text" id="phone" name"phone">
```

try this

Comment: use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: Please try and let me know.